# How can i get data from array of object like serial number in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, mapping

How can i get data from array of object like serial number in reactjs

## `const number = [1, 2, 3] i want to get get data like this number = 1,2,3.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map method to iterate over the array of numbers and extract the values you want to use.

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
const serialNumbers = numbers.map(number => number).join(",");
console.log(serialNumbers);
```

Comment: You do realise that the `.map(number => number)` part does nothing, right? (Even though that's the only part you highlight in your accompanying text!). It's `join` that does all the work here.

Answer (score 0):

The join method unites the array with the parameter that you pass to it, in this case none

```
number.join('')
```